# Add cache to ajax json request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, caching

I have a basic ajax call to parse a json file. I need to make sure I am not hitting the feed every time someone visits the page. How would I go about adding some sort of cache so the feed only get's requested say every say 2 hours?

```
 $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "my.json",
                success: function (data) {
                // do something with the data
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use cookie store your time and check every time to know 2 hours time gap then you can call your function get the latest feed.

Answer (score 0):

By default, is should get cached. You can set the option explicitly as shown below.

```
$(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: true,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "my.json",
            success: function (data) {
            // do something with the data
    }
});
```

You can also use the below statement for all ajax calls on the page.

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: true});
```